# Windows "Problem" after installing Ubuntu, what is it?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, asus, bios

I saw Ubuntu 12.04 yesterday and decided to install it.

First I went to the BIOS, then selected Security> I / O interface Security> New interface card  and set it to locked.  This is the only way I can get into Ubuntu.

Next I installed Ubuntu the usual way. It worked great(except for the login sound; I missed it).

Then I went booting into Windows 7.  The Windows logo kept spinning as usual, then it stopped.  Next my computer restarted itself and said that there is a "problem" with Windows so I have to run the Windows recovery partition to repair.  Then it goes through a 1-hour long process and restarted again.  I chose Windows from the GRUB menu and Windows booted.

The question is:  What is the anonymous problem that happened to Windows?  I am planning to re-install Ubuntu now (because I messed with the boot screen, now it's gone and shutting down takes forever) and I don't want to run into that problem again.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: Re installed Ubuntu and this time nothing happens.

Specs: ASUS F81Se, Windows 7 Dual-boot

Comment: So now you landed safely, OK.Usually it is better to start windows instead of Ubuntu,immediately after the installation and allows windows to repair the partition.It works for me often.

Comment: Maybe it's because I disabled the acpi...

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the size of your Windows partition during the first install?
If you did, I suppose Windows did an in-depth check of it's partition when it realized it's size had changed. That would explain why the second install worked flawlessly - Windows didn't notice any changes and could boot normally.